# Where can I find Nefazadone CBASP dataset?

Tags: data-request, medical

I am searching for data that was collected as part of the job described in the New England Journal of Medicine article [A Comparison of Nefazodone, the Cognitive Behavioral-Analysis System of Psychotherapy, and Their Combination for the Treatment of Chronic Depression](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM200005183422001#t=articleTop).

I have seen many articles that use this data and it seems that this data should be open, but I cannot find it.
All of these articles contains citation to the aforementioned paper.

Does anyone know where I can get this dataset?